# How to create a proper Login Google Button in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-google-login

I've been trying to create a Login/Sign In Google Button to my page using react(testing this framework for the first time), but it just seems just not work.

I'm currently following some tutorials that I could find in the internet, but it still doesn't work.

Just to summarize, I'm currently using tailwind, react and sanity.io in order to build this small project.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading!

```js
import React from "react";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from "@react-oauth/google";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import shareVideo from "../assets/covenlogin.mp4";
import logo from "../assets/logo.png";

import { client } from "../client";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));

    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: "user",
      UserName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };

    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen">
      <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <video
          src={shareVideo}
          type="video/mp4"
          loop
          controls={false}
          muted
          autoPlay
          className="w-full h-full object-cover"
        />

        <div className="absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay">
          <div className="p-5">
            <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={**censored**}>
            <div className="shadow-2xl">
              <GoogleLogin
                clientId={**censored**}
                render={(renderProps) => (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none"
                    onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                    disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                  >
                    <FcGoogle className="mr-4" /> Sign in with your Google
                    Account
                  </button>
                )}
                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                onFailure={responseGoogle}
                cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
              />
            </div>
          </GoogleOAuthProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the JavaScript Mastery tutorial. That google login npm package no longer works. Use this and follow the process in the setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google

Comment: Thanks for the help, pal! If possible, do you know the answer for my other question posted here(in stackoverflow)?

Comment: Glad it helped. Which other questions?

Comment: This one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74116999/how-to-connect-my-loginmade-using-react-with-my-sanity-io)